# pdftk - combining multiple pdf files with php

Tags: php, pdf, pdftk, php-pdftk

I am using [php-pdftk](https://github.com/mikehaertl/php-pdftk) and I am trying to make 1 pdf out of multiple pdfs.

I have all my pdfs in an array however I couldn't figure out how to combine them into one.

```
$pdfFiles = ['a.pdf', 'b.pdf', 'c.pdf']

$pdf = new Pdf($dir. '/Combined.pdf');

foreach ($pdfFiles as $form) {
        $pdf->
      // I am stuck here
}
```

How can I perform this task with php-pdftk? I believe it's around [here](https://github.com/mikehaertl/php-pdftk#cat) but I couldn't figure out

Answer (score -1):

According to documentation of PDFTK you need to use `cat` function

https://github.com/mikehaertl/php-pdftk?tab=readme-ov-file#cat

```
// Combine pages from several files
$pdf = new Pdf([
    'A' => '/path/file1.pdf',                 // A is alias for file1.pdf
    'B' => ['/path/file2.pdf','pass**word'],  // B is alias for file2.pdf
    'C' => ['/path/file3.pdf','secret**pw'],  // C is alias for file3.pdf
]);
$result = $pdf->cat(1, 5, 'A')                // pages 1-5 from A
    ->cat(3, null, 'B')             // page 3 from B
    ->cat(7, 'end', 'B', null, 'east') // pages 7-end from B, rotated East
    ->cat('end',3,'A','even')       // even pages 3-end in reverse order from A
    ->cat([2,3,7], 'C')             // pages 2,3 and 7 from C
    ->saveAs('/path/new.pdf');
```

Answer (score -2):

There are several ways you can do this, though this is probably what you are looking for.

```
$pdfFiles = ['a.pdf', 'b.pdf', 'c.pdf']

$pdf = new Pdf();

foreach ($pdfFiles as $form) {
    $pdf->addPage($form);
}

$pdf->saveAs($dir. '/Combined.pdf');
```

Comment: The method addPage() doesn't exist using PDFTK